# How do I change the URL Alias for Security/login in SilverStripe to user/login

Tags: php, oop, routes, url-routing, silverstripe

I am working on a new website being built in SilverStripe. Currently I am having a ton of trouble trying to get the system to let me change the URL alias (or create a second one) for the Security controller's login (and eventually logout) function.

I have tried playing around with the routes.yml file and I tried creating the paths in my own UserController and loading directly from the Security controller with "return Security::login()". But that gives me errors about the use of the static functions.

Unfortunately I don't come from a ton of object oriented experience and this is the first CMS I have used that actually uses a bunch of true object orientation. The current version of SilverStripe we are using is 3.0 (but we will be upgrading to 3.1.1 in a few days).

Does anyone know much about the routing in SilverStripe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you stated correctly, SilverStripe has routes, and they can be defined in a yaml config file.

if you take a look at the existing `routes.yml` in the framework you can see how the default security route is defined:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/fd6a1619cb7696d0f7e3ab344bc5ac7d9f6cfe77/_config/routes.yml#L17

if you just want to replace the `Secuirty` in `Secuirty/login`, its as easy as just creating your own `routes.yml`in `mysite/_config/` with the following content:

```
---
Name: myroutesorsomeotherrandomname
Before: '*'
After:
  - '#rootroutes'
  - '#coreroutes'
  - '#modelascontrollerroutes'
  - '#adminroutes'
---
Director:
  rules:
    'foobar//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'Security'
```

**NOTE**: make sure you ran a ?flush=1 to ensure the yml file is loaded (they get cached)
also make sure you use spaces in the yml file, if you use tabs you are going to have a bad time

---

if you however wish to also replace `/login` and `/logout` this is no longer a thing for routing.
login and logout are actions (php functions that are listed in Security::$allowed_actions and thus available as URL) on the on Security.
but its still rather easy, just subclass Security and create the actions you want:

```
<?php

class MySuperSecurity extends Security {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
        'showMeTheLoginForm',
        'alternative_login_action_with_dashes',
        'doTheLogout',
    );

    function showMeTheLoginForm() {
        // can be visited via http://website.com/foobar/showMeTheLoginForm
        return $this->login();
    }

    function alternative_login_action_with_dashes() {
        // can be visited via http://website.com/foobar/alternative-login-action-with-dashes
        return $this->login();
    }

    function doTheLogout($redirect = true) {
        // can be visited via http://website.com/foobar/doTheLogout
        return $this->logout($redirect);
    }
}
```

and make the route point to your new class instead of Security inside the `routes.yml`:

```
    'foobar//$Action/$ID/$OtherID': 'MySuperSecurity'
```

**NOTE**: again, make sure you did a ?flush=1, both the `private static $allowed_actions` as well as the yml config file are cached by silverstripe.
**NOTE**: both solutions suggested in this post will create an additional route to login and does not replace the existing one, so the old `Security/login` will still be available

Comment: Ok, well I think this presents a few other problems. First, what if I want only "user/login" and "user/logout" mapped to security. But then I want "user/edit" going to my own module. It would seem that this method above for foobar maps all sub-actions of foobar to Security. Also, what if I just want the paths to be "/login" and "/logout"?

Comment: I would solve both of those problems using a class like `MySuperSecurity`, not sure if there is another way.

Comment: Ah, I guess I could make it inherit from Security instead of the Page_Controller. And then build my other user functions that way.

Comment: you can make `MySuperSecurity` be a sort of proxy and just call methods on other controllers

Comment: there is probably also a way how to handle the urls differently, but I have to admit I haven't figured out how yet.

Comment: In this case I have decided to change my UserPage class to extend Security and not define a login/logut function. Instead I allowed the actions and let it inherit the functions from it's parent. Once I set the route 'user//$Action/$ID/$Name' : 'UserPage_Controller' to point to the UserPage controller and flushed SilverStripe it worked great for "user/login" and "user/logout". Thanks! I will post my other progresses with this here too. I am slowly absorbing the SilverStripe system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nothing about SilverStripe excepting that is a CMS, but i think SilverStripe must provide a way to aliases Url. Also an alternative is create Alias in virtual host definition if you're using apache or in .htaccess file. Refer to apache doc to further details. If you post a skeleton of your .htaccess file or VirtualHost definition i could help you.

Comment: They have a routes file and a $url_handlers variable. But I am clearly missing something if I am to believe that I can change an existing core alias to a new one. Those seem to mainly work for what you create in your "mysite" folder. It has occurred to me to do a masked redirect using the .htaccess. But that is problematic in that all the other URLs are registered with the system, but this won't be and so it breaks standard. It also creates issues when you want to ask the system what the available URLs are.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box and suggesting mod_rewrite. however I would solve it using silverstripe